# Evaluating Poker hands texas holdem Issue

Tags: java, math, poker

I am having issues getting the correct solution to an online problem where I am getting more instances of player 1 winning than player 2 winning. Could you please look at my code and find the issue thanks.

I know that this code is complete trash but please be nice.

I think there might be an issue in the two Pair method because it considers three of a kind a two pair but I didn't think this would cause any issues

```
public static boolean firstHandWinsArray(Card[] h1, Card[] h2){

        //Straight Flushes
        int a = getStraightFlush(h1);
        int b = getStraightFlush(h2);
        if(a > b){
            return true;
        }
        if(a < b){
            return false;
        }


        //Four of a kind check
        a = getFourOfAKind(h1);
        b = getFourOfAKind(h2);

        if(a > b){
            return true;
        }
        if(a < b){
            return false;
        }


        //Full house check
        Point p1 = getFullHouse(h1);
        Point p2 = getFullHouse(h2);

        if(p1.x > p2.x){
            return true;
        }
        if(p1.x < p2.x){
            return false;
        }
        if(p1.x == p2.x){
            if(p1.y > p2.y){
                return true;
            }
            if(p1.y < p2.y){
                return false;
            }
        }


        //Flush check
        a = getFlush(h1);
        b = getFlush(h2);

        if(a > b){
            return true;
        }
        if(a < b){
            return false;
        }


        //Straight Check
        a = getStraight(h1);
        b = getStraight(h2);

        if(a > b){
            return true;
        }
        if(a < b){
            return false;
        }


        //Three of a kind check
        a = threeOfAKind(h1);
        b = threeOfAKind(h2);

        if(a > b){
            return true;
        }
        if(a < b){
            return false;
        }


        //Two pair check
        p1 = twoPair(h1);
        p2 = twoPair(h2);

        int pair1High = Math.max(p1.x, p1.y);
        int pair1Low = Math.min(p1.x, p1.y);
        int pair2High = Math.max(p2.x, p2.y);
        int pair2Low = Math.min(p2.x, p2.y);

        if(pair1High > pair2High){
            return true;
        }
        if(pair1High < pair2High){
            return false;
        }
        if(pair1High == pair2High){
            if(pair1Low > pair2Low){
                return true;
            }
            if(pair1Low < pair2Low){
                return false;
            }
        }


        //Pair compare
        a = highestPair(h1);
        b = highestPair(h2);

        if(a > b){
            return true;
        }
        if(a < b){
            return false;
        }


        //High card
        return firstHandHigher(h1, h2);
    }


    public static int getStraightFlush(Card[] c){
        int flush = getFlush(c);
        if(flush > -1 && getStraight(c) > -1){
            return flush;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static int getFourOfAKind(Card[] c){
        int[] temp = new int[c.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
            for(int a = 0; a < c.length; a++){
                if(c[a].getValue() == c[i].getValue()){
                    temp[i] = temp[i] + 1;
                }
            }
        }


        ArrayList<Integer> check = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int a: temp){
            check.add(a);
        }

        if(check.contains(4)){
            return c[check.indexOf(4)].getValue();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static Point getFullHouse(Card[] c){
        int[] temp = new int[c.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
            for(int a = 0; a < c.length; a++){
                if(c[a].getValue() == c[i].getValue()){
                    temp[i] = temp[i] + 1;
                }
            }
        }


        ArrayList<Integer> check = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int a: temp){
            check.add(a);
        }
        if(check.contains(3) && check.contains(2)) {
            return new Point(c[check.indexOf(3)].getValue(), c[check.indexOf(2)].getValue());
        }

        return new Point(-1, -1);
    }




    public static int getFlush(Card[] cards){
        int suit = cards[0].getSuit();
        int min = cards[0].getValue();

        for(int i = 1; i < cards.length; i++){
            if(cards[i].getValue() < min){
                min = cards[i].getValue();
            }
            if(cards[i].getSuit() != suit){
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    //returns starting value of straight if it is one or it returns -1; Must have at least 2 items in the array
    public static int getStraight(Card[] c) {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
            temp.add(c[i].getValue());
        }

        int min = 99;

        for(int a: temp){
            if(a < min){
                min = a;
            }
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
            if(!temp.contains(min + i)) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        return min;
    }




    //Returns value of three pair in hand if there is none it returns -1
    public static int threeOfAKind(Card[] cards){

        for(int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
            for(int n = i+1; n < cards.length; n++){
                if(cards[i].getValue() == cards[n].getValue()){
                    for(int x = n+1; x < cards.length; x++){
                        if(cards[x].getValue() == cards[n].getValue()){
                            return cards[x].getValue();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        return -1;
    }

    //Integer value of value of highest pair in the hand is returned
    public static int highestPair(Card[] c1) {
        int highest = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < c1.length; i++){
            for(int n = i+1; n < c1.length; n++){
                if(c1[i].getValue() == c1[n].getValue() && c1[i].getValue() > highest){
                    highest = c1[i].getValue();
                }
            }
        }
        return highest;
    }

    //A point containing one pair's value in Point.x and the other in Point.y ** as This method is somewhat faulty because
    //Three of a kind is considered a two pair but this is irrelevant because of the ranking in the poker hands

    public static Point twoPair(Card[] c1) {
        Point a = new Point(-1, -1);

        for(int i = 0; i < c1.length; i++){
            for(int n = i+1; n < c1.length; n++){
                if(c1[i].getValue() == c1[n].getValue()){
                    if(c1[n].getValue() > a.x || c1[n].getValue() > a.y){
                        if(a.x <= a.y){
                            a.x = c1[n].getValue();
                        }
                        else{
                            a.y = c1[n].getValue();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    }



    public static boolean firstHandHigher(Card[] h1, Card[] h2){
        Card[] copy1 = h1.clone();
        Card[] copy2 = h2.clone();
        int highVal1 = -1;
        int highIndex1 = 0;
        int highVal2 = -1;
        int highIndex2 = 0;





       while(highVal1 == highVal2) {
           for(int i = 0; i < copy1.length; i++){
               if(copy1[i].getValue() > highVal1){
                   highVal1 = copy1[i].getValue();
                   highIndex1 = i;
               }
               if(copy2[i].getValue() > highVal2){
                   highVal2 = copy2[i].getValue();
                   highIndex2 = i;
               }
           }

           if(highVal1 > highVal2){
               return true;
           }
           if(highVal1 < highVal2){
               return false;
           }
           else {
               copy1[highIndex1] = new Card("1D");
               copy2[highIndex2] = new Card("1D");
               highVal1 = -1;
               highVal2 = -1;
           }


       }

        return highVal1 > highVal2;
    }
}




class Card{
//2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack (11), Queen (12), King (13), Ace (14).
//Diamonds (0), Hearts (1), Spades (2), Clubs (3)

    private int value;
    private int suit;


    public Card(String cardString) {

        String suit = cardString.substring(cardString.length()-1);

        switch(suit){
            case "D":
                this.suit = 0;
                break;
            case "H":
                this.suit = 1;
                break;
            case "S":
                this.suit = 2;
                break;
            case "C":
                this.suit = 3;
                break;
        }

        String value = cardString.substring(0, cardString.length()-1);

        try {
            this.value = Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            switch(value){
                case "J":
                    this.value = 11;
                    break;
                case "Q":
                    this.value = 12;
                    break;
                case "K":
                    this.value = 13;
                    break;
                case "A":
                    this.value = 14;
                    break;
            }
        }



    }

    public int getSuit(){
        return suit;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }



}
***
```

Comment: I doubt many would debug your code. I think you should try to narrow down the problem-space so that a programmer can read it and understand it in 5 minutes or less. That would help you a lot. I would like to help, but cannot afford to allocate the necessary time into reading your full code.

Comment: Please [edit] the question so that it contains a [mre].